# Why do my elements displace when I split screen or zoom out?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to find the correct method for this. The problem also occurs when I zoom out/in or if I try to scroll down. How can I fix this? I want my page to be static and not fluid if that makes sense. I would appreciate anyone's help. Here are my HTML and CSS code:

[this is the example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc2je.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
    
<body>
    
    <div class = "music-player">
        <h1 class="music-name">Fall</h1>
        <p class= "artist-name">Joni Van Rossum, Jurrivh</p>
        <div class = "disk"></div>

        <div class="song-slider"></div>
          <input type="range" value="0" class="seek-bar">  
          <span class="current-time" >00:00</span>
          <span class="song-duration-time">00:00</span>
    </div>



    <script src = "script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:#3b9c94;
    font-family: 'Fire Sans' , proxima-nova;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: justify;
}

.music-player{
    width: 350px;
    height: 550px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #5cc6b5;
    box-shadow: 0 40px 100px #00f0c8;
}

.music-name, .artist-name{
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin: 20px 490px;
    
 
}

.music-name{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:-5px;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #183b39;
}

.artist-name{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:170px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #183b39;
}

.disk{
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 80px auto;
    width: 230px;
    height:230px;
    border-radius: 2%;
    background-image: url('fall.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #2b6f65;
}

.disk::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: #5cc6b5;
}

.song-slider{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.seek-bar{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 90%;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 30px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4ea99a;
}

.seek-bar::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #2b6f65;
    box-shadow: -400px 0 0 400px #ffffff;
}

.current-time, 
.song-duration-time{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.song-duration-time{
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    
   
}
```

[the result should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OS3o.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's because all of the [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) on `.music-name, .artist-name`. Also, change [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) from `left` to `center`, and you'll be good to go.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #3b9c94;
    font-family: "Fire Sans", proxima-nova;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: justify;
}

.music-player {
    width: 350px;
    height: 550px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #5cc6b5;
    box-shadow: 0 40px 100px #00f0c8;
}

.music-name,
.artist-name {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.music-name {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: -5px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #183b39;
}

.artist-name {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #183b39;
}

.disk {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 80px auto;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border-radius: 2%;
    background-image: url("fall.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #2b6f65;
}

.disk::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: #5cc6b5;
}

.song-slider {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.seek-bar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 90%;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 30px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4ea99a;
}

.seek-bar::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #2b6f65;
    box-shadow: -400px 0 0 400px #ffffff;
}

.current-time,
.song-duration-time {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.song-duration-time {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Music Player</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="music-player">
            <h1 class="music-name">Fall</h1>
            <p class="artist-name">Joni Van Rossum, Jurrivh</p>
            <div class="disk"></div>
            <div class="song-slider"></div>
            <input type="range" value="0" class="seek-bar" />
            <span class="current-time">00:00</span>
            <span class="song-duration-time">00:00</span>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```